# Users Answering Already Asked-Answered Questions Rather Than Community Moderating Them

Tags: discussion

For example:
[Resize uploaded images](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/84439/resize-uploaded-images)

This was yet another variation on the "how do I regenerate my thumbnails?" question. It's been asked and answered *ad nauseum*, and I'm sure it will end up getting closed accordingly.

That said: as often happens between initial close-vote and eventual closure, the question solicits answers.

Should we deal with this? And if so, how?

The only options I can think of initially are both sub-optimal:

1. Down-vote the answer, and leave a comment regarding not posting answers to obvious duplicate questions
2. Flag the answer

Is there a better way to deal with this? Or should we just ignore it, knowing that the question will eventually get closed anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring is usual (and efficient :) approach.

Note that if question that is being closed as duplicate has excellent answers moderator can  *merge* them into earlier question.